# Using esc_attr_e

Tags: escaping

From what I understand `esc_attr_e` is ideally used for escaping values in attributes - Is it right that the usage of `esc_attr_e` can also be worked in with non attribute values, such as the h3 and label elements in the example below?

```
<h3><?php esc_attr_e( 'Some Text', 'my-plugin' ); ?></h3>


<form name="myplugin_form" method="post" action="">

        <input type="hidden" name="myplugin_form_submitted" value="Y">

    <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="ng_plugin_menu"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Plugin Menu Name', 'my-plugin' ); ?></label></td>
                <td><input name="ng_plugin_menu" id="ng_plugin_menu" type="text" value="<?php esc_attr_e ($my_plugin_label, 'my_plugin'); ?>" class="regular-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e ('Placeholder Text', 'my_plugin'); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>

    </table>
    <p><input class="button-primary" type="submit" name="my_plugin_menu_submit" value="Save" /></p>

</form>
```

So using `esc_attr_e` it instead of `_e`, I was told by a senior developer that this is valid, but am looking for confirmation. It is also the purpose of my sample code that I want to allow translation for all strings.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `esc_html` instead of `esc_attr` for that, e.g.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $url );?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $classes ); ?>">
    <?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?>
</a>
<div>
    <?php echo wp_kses_post( $html_with_safe_tags );?>
</div>
<script>
    <?php echo wp_json_encode( $data_for_js ); ?>
</script>
```

There is also:

- `esc_html__` `esc_attr__` etc ( escape translations too! )
- `esc_js` - escape strings for javascript e.g. `console.log(<?php echo esc_js($var); ?>);`
- `esc_url_raw` when redirecting, use this instead
- `esc_sql`
- `esc_textarea`
- `sanitize_text_field`
- Whitelisting values
- type casting with `(int)` or `absint`
- and others

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is valid.
as stands in reference https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr_e/
This function displays translated text that has been escaped for safe use in an attribute and what is safe for attribute is certainly safe in html text.

For simple strings (like 'Plugin Menu Name') this functions returns same output, but if you can, I recommend using appropriate function as already Tom J Nowell listed.